# OCserv error: unknown user

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, anyconnect

I'm on ubuntu 18 and these are the lines causing the issue while starting up OCserv

```
run-as-user = nobody
run-as-group = daemon
```

I've tried a lot of other combinations but I'm out of luck

Comment: Does the `nobody` user actually exist? `getent passwd | grep nobody`

Comment: @Mugurel nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin that's what I get. It means its inexistent?

Comment: No, that basically says the home directory of this user is `/nonexistent`. How did you install ocserv, did the package create a username for OCserv? I'd use that. Check for any entries in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @Mugurel No it didn't create a username for OCserv.